# Serial Port data capturing issue

Tags: c#, .net

I receive serial port data in the textbox when i connect the GPS device to the serial port, But when i connect the Aristel rv20 PBX to the same port, the received data from PBX is not shown in the textbox. what would i miss?

Comment: I found a solution, actually i don't enable the Data Terminal. so I enable it in the 
StartListening() method like that:

_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

it enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions here.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so that folks don't check back trying to fix something that is already solved :)

Comment: Firstly i post my solution as an answer but due to reputation is lower than 10 it will accept my solution as an answer after 8 hours.So be patient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, actually i don't enable the Data Terminal. so I enable it in the 
StartListening() method like that:

_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

it enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication.